# Xcode 6: iOS 8.1 The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I keep getting this error, whenever I try to run my app on my iphone, which is running iOS 8.1.-

> **The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted.**
>
> User’s iPhone may be running a version of iOS that is not supported
>   by this version of Xcode.

I tried restarting my mac and xcode, but problem persists.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Xcode 6 only contains the iOS 8.0 SDK.

If you're running iOS 8.1 on your phone, then you'll need to upgrade to Xcode **6.1**, which contains the iOS 8.1 SDK.

Comment: this answers my question as well and I'm ready to upgrade, but does Xcode 6.1 still allow me to build for iOS 6.0?

Comment: My app is developed in xcode 4, and 6.1.1 does a mess with layouts, so I have to run it on Xcode 6.0.1, on iOS 8.0, This helped me http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/148010

Answer (score 11):

Download the [latest version of Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) from the App Store. I had an early version of XCode 6.1 that lacked the 8.1 SDK. Upgrading to the latest fixed the problem.

Comment: The OSX App Store "Updates" was telling me my Xcode was up to date, but searching for and opening Xcode in the app store it displayed an 'Install' button so obviously an update was available but just not listed in Updates.

Answer (score 8):

Restarting my phone cleared this for me.

It started a day after updating to Xcode 6.1 and phone (4s) to 8.1 worked fine to start with then stopped with this message a day later.

Answer (score 5):

Opening project in Xcode 6.1 then again in 6.0.1 seemed to fix issue, if your project is not ready to be compiled in 6.1!

Comment: In my case, I need to work with XCode 6.2. Opening with the last XCode (7.2.1) then again with 6.2 did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check your apps' base version. If the base version is set to 8 and your device is 7, you will probably get this error.

and if your base version, from what i imagine is 8.1 and your device is not updated to 8.1 it wont work either.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.4 beta would not run iOS 8.3. Switched to Xcode 6.3 fixed the issue. And then when opening it back in 6.4 beta, was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this after absentmindedly upgrading my phone to iOS 8.3. Resolution required an upgrade to OS X Yosemite (10.10) before I could update to a version of Xcode that supports that version of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error before in my experience. It means that the Developer Disk image in your Xcode is not compatible with the one in your iOS device that you are trying to run/develop an app with. One of the easiest way to solve this is update your Xcode installation. Another quick trick that I learned with is by copying Developer Disk image versions into Xcode.app's directory.

I earned some copies of different versions of Developer Disk image from various Macbooks that have updated and outdated Developer Disk images. You could download some resources online, extract it and then place the whole directory on your Xcode's installation directory normally located here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`.

I hope this helps!